# Install adb/sdk

Tags: 10.10, android

I'm trying to install adb/sdk in my droid so that I can root my phone and eventually mess around with a custom ROM. I'm using the instruction here:

http://androidadvices.com/how-to-install-set-up-and-use-adb-for-android-devices/

It says to download the sdk file and then find the sdk manager file. However, I'm not finding any sdk manager files in the tar.gz file.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it says "As you have downloaded **and installed** the SDK in the last step in the computer..."

See [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html) for more details on the installation procedure